# How does RSA decryption works?

Tags: rsa

I have this exercise:

> we have the following RSA public key 
>   $n = 275398901700898900724918474136345950999$ 
>   $e = 5$ 
>   Alice encrypts the message $M$ with the native RSA. She computes $C = M^e \pmod n$ and sends to Bob 
>   $C = 170841202002112185870598344402287193795$
>   Recover the original message $M$.

I'm playing some ctf online. I'm new in crypto and just want to know if I can decrypt the message using a tool.

Comment: [Some more readings](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/calculating-rsa-private-exponent-when-given-public-exponent-and-the-modulus-fact).

Comment: [and mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31465/rsa-attack-known-public-key-and-ciphertext-can-decrypt-the-message-m?rq=1)

Comment: did you actually search ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a dump of a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an homework question so my answer won't be an answer but the very basic steps to find your answer. I let voluntarily enough informations hidden so you still have some work to do.

1. [Factorise $n$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=275398901700898900724918474136345950999)
2. find $d$ the private key using [$\varphi(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
3. compute $C^d \pmod n$ this should be your initial $M$.